# Text input cell values clears in table when scrolling

Tags: sapui5, binding-context

I have an input text value box in a table column in each table row. That data is fetched initially and populates in that particular table cell initially. This cell is editable by the user where it can be later saved in the DB upon clicking on a save button.

However the issue occurs when the user input the value in text field and scrolls up and down. The value gets cleared and defaults to the default fetched one. Is there anyway I can prevent that? When the table has small number of records this is not an issue rather the issue occurs when you have a large set of rows.

Does this has any configuration at table level or do I need to implement some soft of eventing mechanism for text inputs?

Here is the code.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "sap/ui/table/Table",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
    "sap/ui/ux3/FacetFilter",
    "sap/m/TablePersoController",
    "sap/m/UploadCollectionParameter",
    "sap/m/MessageBox"

], function(Controller, MessageToast, JSONModel, Device, models, Filter, FilterOperator, TablePersoController) {
    "use strict";
    var dataPath;
    var oModel;
    var that;
    var items;
    var jModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    var result = {};
    var ppernr;
    var from_date;
    var to_date;
    var oTableEntry;

    var t_ttwork = 0;
    var t_ttout = 0;
    var t_ttoin = 0;
    var t_ttShift = 0;
    var t_ttmhrs = 0;
    var t_tthrapp = 0;
    var t_AddHRs = 0;
    var t_Syshr = 0;
    var t_Penalty = 0;

    function roundToTwo(num) {
        return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
    }

    return Controller.extend("OVERTIME.controller.OTMain", {
        onInit: function() {
        //  dataPath = "/webidedispatcher/destinations/AV_GWD/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZHRPT_OVERTIME_SRV/";
                dataPath = "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZHRPT_OVERTIME_SRV/";
            oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(dataPath);
            that = this;
            that.setDates();
            that.GET_DATA();
        },
        GET_DATA: function(oEvent) {
            result.historySet = [];
            //  var URI = "/EMP_DETAILSSet?$filter=Pernr eq '" + pernr + "'";
            oModel.read("/EMP_DETAILSSet/", null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
                result.EMP_DETAILSSet = oData.results;
                items = result.EMP_DETAILSSet;
                result.historySet = oData.results;
                jModel.setData(result);
                that.getView().setModel(jModel);

            });
        },
        OnPressList: function(oEvent) {
            t_ttwork = 0;
            t_ttout = 0;
            t_ttoin = 0;
            t_ttShift = 0;
            t_ttmhrs = 0;
            t_tthrapp = 0;
            t_AddHRs = 0;
            t_Syshr = 0;
            t_Penalty = 0;
            if (items !== "") {
                var BindingContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
                result.EMP_DATASet = BindingContext.getProperty();
                jModel.setData(result);
                that.getView().setModel(jModel);
                ppernr = BindingContext.getProperty("Pernr");

                that.getData();
            }
        },

        getData: function() {
            if (ppernr !== undefined) {
                from_date = that.getView().byId("fdate").getValue();
                to_date = that.getView().byId("tdate").getValue();
                var oFilter = new Array();
                oFilter[0] = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Pernr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, ppernr);
                oFilter[1] = new sap.ui.model.Filter("FromDate", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, from_date);
                oFilter[2] = new sap.ui.model.Filter("ToDate", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, to_date);
                var oTable = this.getView().byId("oTable");
                //this.getView().setModel(oModel);
                oTable.setModel(oModel);
                oTable.bindRows({
                    //method: "GET",
                    path: '/EE_OVETIMESet/',
                    filters: oFilter

                });
                //  that.OnCalc();

            } else {
                //  MessageToast.show("Please select employee first");
                sap.m.MessageBox.show("Please select employee first", {
                    icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
                    title: "Error",
                    onClose: function(evt) {}
                });
            }
        },
        OnCalc: function() {
            oTableEntry = this.getView().byId("oTable");
            var count = oTableEntry._getRowCount();
            var oTData;
            var cells;
            var hour_inoffice = 0;
            var minute_inoffice = 0;
            var hour_shift = 0;
            var minute_shift = 0;
            var hour_manual = 0;
            var minute_manual = 0;
            var hour_sys = 0;
            var minute_sys = 0;
            var hour_hr = 0;
            var minute_hr = 0;
            //  var second = 0;
            t_ttoin = 0;
            t_ttShift = 0;
            t_ttmhrs = 0;
            t_tthrapp = 0;
            t_Syshr = 0;
            t_AddHRs = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                oTData = oTableEntry.getContextByIndex(i).getObject();
                //cells = oTableEntry.getRows()[i].getCells();
                var hrAppValue = oTableEntry.getRows()[i].getCells()[9]._lastValue;

                if (oTData.InOffice !== "") {
                    var splitTime1 = oTData.InOffice.split(':');
                    hour_inoffice = hour_inoffice + parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                    minute_inoffice = minute_inoffice + parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                }
                if (oTData.EligableHours !== "") {
                    var splitTime1 = oTData.EligableHours.split(':');
                    hour_shift = hour_shift + parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                    minute_shift = minute_shift + parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                }
                if (oTData.ManualOvt !== "") {
                    var splitTime1 = oTData.ManualOvt.split(':');
                    hour_manual = hour_manual + parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                    //minute_manual = minute_manual + parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                }
                if (oTData.TimeDiff !== "") {
                    var splitTime1 = oTData.TimeDiff.split(':');
                    if (splitTime1[0].charAt(0) === "+") {
                        splitTime1[0] = splitTime1[0].replace('+', '');
                        hour_sys = hour_sys + parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                        minute_sys = minute_sys + parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                    } else {
                        splitTime1[0] = splitTime1[0].replace('-', '');
                        hour_sys = hour_sys - parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                        minute_sys = minute_sys - parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                    }
                }
                if (hrAppValue !== "") {
                    var splitTime1 = hrAppValue.split(':');
                    if (splitTime1[0].charAt(0) === "+") {
                        splitTime1[0] = splitTime1[0].replace('+', '');
                        hour_hr = hour_hr + parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                        minute_hr = minute_hr + parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                    } else {
                        splitTime1[0] = splitTime1[0].replace('-', '');
                        hour_hr = hour_hr - parseInt(splitTime1[0]);
                        minute_hr = minute_hr - parseInt(splitTime1[1]);
                    }
                }
                /* minute_inoffice = minute_inoffice%60;
                second_inoffice = parseInt(splitTime1[2]);
                minute_inoffice = minute_inoffice + second_inoffice/60;
                second_inoffice = second_inoffice%60;*/

                /*  if (parseFloat(cells[3].getText()) > 0) {
                        t_ttwork = parseFloat(t_ttwork) + parseFloat(cells[3].getText().replace(':', '.'));
                    }
                    t_ttout = parseFloat(t_ttout) + parseFloat(cells[4].getText().replace(':', '.'));
                    t_ttoin = parseFloat(t_ttoin) + parseFloat(cells[5].getText().replace(':', '.'));
                    t_ttShift = parseFloat(t_ttShift) + parseFloat(cells[6].getText()); //.replace(':', '.'));
                    t_ttmhrs = parseFloat(t_ttmhrs) + parseFloat(cells[7].getText().replace(':', '.'));
                    t_tthrapp = parseFloat(t_tthrapp) + parseFloat(cells[9].getValue().replace(':', '.'));
                    if (parseFloat(cells[9].getValue().replace(':', '.')) > 0) {
                        t_AddHRs = parseFloat(t_AddHRs) + parseFloat(cells[9].getValue());
                    } else if (parseFloat(cells[9].getValue().replace(':', '.')) < 0) {
                        t_Penalty = parseFloat(t_Penalty) + parseFloat(cells[9].getValue());
                    }*/

            }
            var temp;
            t_ttoin = roundToTwo(hour_inoffice + minute_inoffice / 60);
            t_ttShift = roundToTwo(hour_shift + minute_shift / 60);
            t_ttmhrs = hour_manual;
            t_Syshr = roundToTwo(hour_sys + minute_sys / 60);
            t_AddHRs = roundToTwo(hour_hr + minute_hr / 60);
            /*  temp = t_ttoin ;
                temp = '.' + temp.split('.') ;
                temp[1] = temp[1] * 60 ;
                t_ttoin = temp[0] + ':' + temp[1] ;*/
            //  this.getView().byId("t_ttwork").setValue(t_ttwork);
            //  this.getView().byId("t_ttoout").setValue(t_ttout);
            this.getView().byId("t_ttoin").setValue(t_ttoin);
            this.getView().byId("t_ttShift").setValue(t_ttShift);
            this.getView().byId("t_ttmhrs").setValue(t_ttmhrs);
            this.getView().byId("t_tsyshr").setValue(t_Syshr);
            this.getView().byId("t_tthrapp").setValue(t_AddHRs);
            //  this.getView().byId("t_Penalty").setValue(t_Penalty);
        },
        setDates: function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate().toString();
            var mm = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString(); //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var date = yyyy.toString().concat((mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]).toString(), '01');
            this.getView().byId("fdate").setValue(date);

            var lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 15);
            lastDay = yyyy.toString().concat((mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]).toString(), lastDay.getDate());
            this.getView().byId("tdate").setValue(lastDay);
        },
        OngetData: function(oEvent) {
            that.getData();
        },
        OnSave: function(oEvent) {

            var oTEntry = this.getView().byId("oTable");
            var count = oTEntry._getRowCount();
            var cells;


            var bodyArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var oTData = oTEntry.getContextByIndex(i).getObject();
                //cells = oTableEntry.getRows()[i].getCells();
                var hrAppValue = oTableEntry.getRows()[i].getCells()[9]._lastValue;

                var requestBody = {};
                requestBody.Pernr = "" + oTData.Pernr;
                requestBody.FromDate = "" + oTData.FromDate;
                requestBody.ToDate = "" + oTData.ToDate;
                requestBody.OtDate = "" + oTData.OtDate;
                requestBody.FcIn = "" + oTData.FcIn;
                requestBody.LcOut = "" + oTData.LcOut;
                requestBody.LogicHours = "" + oTData.LogicHours;
                requestBody.OutOffice = "" + oTData.OutOffice;
                requestBody.InOffice = "" + oTData.InOffice;
                requestBody.EligableHours = "" + oTData.EligableHours;
                requestBody.ManualOvt = "" + oTData.ManualOvt;
                requestBody.HrApp = "" + hrAppValue; //oTData.HrApp;

                bodyArray.push(requestBody);

            }

            var Sflag;


            for (var i = 0; i < bodyArray.length; i++) {

                oModel.create("/EE_OVETIMESet", bodyArray[i], {
                    success: function(oData, oResponse) {
                        Sflag = "S";
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        Sflag = "E";
                        break;
                    }
                });
            }

            /**oModel.create("/EE_OVETIMESet", bodyArray, {
                success: function(oData, oResponse) {
                    Sflag = "S";
                },
                error: function() {
                    Sflag = "E";
                }
            });*/

            if (Sflag === "S") {
                var msg = "Saved Successfully";
                sap.m.MessageBox.show(msg, {
                    icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,
                    title: "Success",
                    onClose: function(evt) {}
                });
            } else {
                sap.m.MessageBox.show("Data Not Saved", {
                    icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
                    title: "Error",
                    onClose: function(evt) {}
                });
            }

        },

        OnApprove: function(oEvent) {
            var requestBody = {};

            requestBody.Pernr = ppernr;
            requestBody.FromDate = from_date;
            requestBody.ToDate = to_date;
            requestBody.Svalue = this.getView().byId("t_AddHRs").getValue();
            requestBody.Pvalue = this.getView().byId("t_Penalty").getValue();

            /*  if (this.getView().byId("addover").getSelected() === true ) {
                    requestBody.Sflag = "A";
                    requestBody.Svalue = this.getView().byId("t_AddHRs").getValue();
                } else if (this.getView().byId("subover").getSelected() === true ) {
                    requestBody.Sflag = "P";
                    requestBody.Pvalue = this.getView().byId("t_Penalty").getValue();
                }*/

            oModel.create("/EE_SOVTSet", requestBody, {
                //  method: "POST",
                success: function(oData, oResponse) {
                    var status = oData.STATUS;
                    if (status === "S") {
                        sap.m.MessageBox.show("Data Saved", {
                            icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,
                            title: "Success",
                            onClose: function(evt) {}
                        });
                    } else if (status === "E") {
                        sap.m.MessageBox.show("Data Not Saved", {
                            icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
                            title: "Error",
                            onClose: function(evt) {}
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    MessageToast.show("Error. Try Again");
                }
            });

        },

        onNavBack: function() {
            window.history.go(-1);
        },
        onSearch: function(oEvt) {
            var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
            if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
                var filter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Pernr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
                var filter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
                var allfilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter([filter1, filter2], false);
            }
            var list = this.getView().byId("idList");
            var binding = list.getBinding("items");
            binding.filter(allfilter);

        }

    });

});
```

View

```
<mvc:View controllerName="OVERTIME.controller.OTMain" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:co="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:sc="sap.ui.core">
    <SplitApp id="idSplitApp">
        <masterPages>
            <Page id="idMaster" title="{i18n>title}" icon="sap-icon://action" class="sapUiSizeCompact">
                <headerContent class="sapUiSizeCompact"></headerContent>
                <subHeader>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <SearchField width="100%" liveChange="onSearch" class="sapUiSizeCompact"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </subHeader>
                <content>
                    <List id="idList" items="{/EMP_DETAILSSet}" class="sapUiSizeCompact">
                        <items class="Masterpage">
                            <ObjectListItem title="{Name}" type="Active" press="OnPressList" class="Masterpage">
                                <firstStatus>
                                    <!--<ObjectStatus text="{Pernr}"/>-->
                                </firstStatus>
                                <attributes>
                                    <ObjectAttribute text="{Pernr}"/>
                                </attributes>
                            </ObjectListItem>
                        </items>
                    </List>
                </content>
                <footer>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </footer>
            </Page>
        </masterPages>
        <detailPages>
            <Page id="idDetails" showHeader="true" title="{i18n>appTitle}" class="sapUiSizeCompact" showNavButton="true" navButtonText="Back"
                navButtonPress="onNavBack">
                <ObjectHeader id="oh1" responsive="true" binding="{/EMP_DATASet}" intro="{i18n>pernr} - {Pernr}" title="{i18n>name} - {Name}"
                    showMarkers="false" markFlagged="false" markFavorite="false" backgroundDesign="Translucent">
                    <attributes>
                        <ObjectAttribute title="{i18n>org}" text="{Orgtx}"/>
                        <ObjectAttribute title="{i18n>posi}" text="{Postx}"/>
                        <ObjectAttribute title="{i18n>group}" text="{Ptext01}"/>
                    </attributes>
                    <statuses>
                        <ObjectStatus title="{i18n>subgroup}" text="{Ptext02}"/>
                        <ObjectStatus title="" text=""/>
                    </statuses>
                </ObjectHeader>
                <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBarMulti" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
                    <items>
                        <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://account">
                            <f:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="fales" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                                id="from_header" title="">
                                <f:content>
                                    <Label text="{i18n>fromdate}" id="l_fdate" required="true"/>
                                    <DatePicker width="30%" id="fdate" valueFormat="yyyyMMdd" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                                    <Label text="{i18n>todate}" id="l_tdate" required="true"/>
                                    <DatePicker width="61%" id="tdate" valueFormat="yyyyMMdd" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                                    <Button id="iddate" press="OngetData" type="Unstyled" icon="sap-icon://display" width="30%"/>
                                </f:content>
                            </f:SimpleForm>
                            <f:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="fales" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                                id="from_overtime" title="">
                                <f:content id="cc">
                                    <ScrollContainer horizontal="true" vertical="false" focusable="true" width="55rem">
                                        <!--<sc:ScrollBarheight="20rem" vertical="false" size = "200px" contentSize = "500px" scrollPosition = "50"> -->
                                        <t:Table selectionMode="None" id="oTable" navigationMode="Paginator" filter="onfilter" showNoData="true" width="70rem" visibleRowCount="16">
                                            <t:columns>
                                                <t:Column id="c_odate" width="10%" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>odate}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_odate" text="{OtDate}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_cin" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>cin}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_cin" text="{FcIn}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_cout" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>cout}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_cout" text="{LcOut}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_lhour" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>lhour}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_lhour" text="{LogicHours}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_toout" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>toout}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_toout" text="{OutOffice}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_toin" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>toin}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_toin" text="{InOffice}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_elhours" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>elhours}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_elhours" text="{EligableHours}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <!--            <t:Column id="c_stime" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>stime}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_stime" text="{TimeDiff}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>-->
                                                <t:Column id="c_mover" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>mover}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_mover" text="{ManualOvt}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_diff" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>tdiff}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_diff" text="{TimeDiff}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <t:Column id="c_hrapp" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>hrapp}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Input id="t_hrapp" value="{HrApp}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>
                                                <!--    <t:Column id="c_ElgHrApp" autoResizable="true">
                                                    <Label text="{i18n>ElgHrApp}"/>
                                                    <t:template>
                                                        <Label id="t_ElgHrApp" text="{ElgHrApp}"/>
                                                    </t:template>
                                                </t:Column>-->
                                            </t:columns>
                                        </t:Table>
                                    </ScrollContainer>
                                    <!--    </sc:ScrollBar>-->
                                </f:content>
                            </f:SimpleForm>
                            <f:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                                id="from_tovertime" title="Totals ">
                                <Button id="idCalc" text="{i18n>Calc}" press="OnCalc" type="Default" icon="sap-icon://simulate" width="10%"/>
                                <f:content id="cc1">
                                    <!--    <Label id="t_twork" text="{i18n>TWOffice}"/>
                                    <Input id="t_ttwork" editable="false" width="40%"/>
                                <Input id="t_ttout" value="{i18n>TOutOffice}" editable="false"/>
                                    <Input id="t_ttoout" type="Number" editable="false"/>-->
                                    <Label id="t_ttin" text="{i18n>TInOffice}"/>
                                    <Input id="t_ttoin" type="Number" editable="false"/>
                                    <Input id="t_tShift" value="{i18n>TShift}" editable="false"/>
                                    <Input id="t_ttShift" type="Number" editable="false"/>
                                    <Label id="t_tmhrs" text="{i18n>Tmhrs}"/>
                                    <Input id="t_ttmhrs" type="Number" editable="false"/>
                                    <Label id="t_syshr" text="{i18n>Tsyshr}"/>
                                    <Input id="t_tsyshr" editable="false" width="40%"/> 
                                    <Input id="t_thrapp" value="{i18n>thrapp}" editable="false"/>
                                    <Input id="t_tthrapp" type="Number" editable="false"/>
                                </f:content>
                            </f:SimpleForm>
                            <f:SimpleForm xmlns:sap.ui.layout.form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveLayout"
                                id="from_tovertime2" title="Approved Hrs ">
                                <f:content >
                                    <!--<RadioButton id="addover" groupName="G1" text="Add Over Hrs" selected="true" valueState="Warning"/>-->
                                    <Label id="l_AddHRs" text="Add Over Hrs"/>
                                    <Input id="t_AddHRs" type="Number" editable="true" width="30%" valueState="Success"/>
                                    <!--<RadioButton id="subover" groupName="G1" text="Add Penalty" valueState="Error"></RadioButton>-->
                                    <Label id="l_Penalty" text="Add Penalty"/>
                                    <Input id="t_Penalty" type="Number" editable="true" width="30%"/>
                                </f:content>
                            </f:SimpleForm>
                        </IconTabFilter>
                        <!--<IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://attachment">
                            <Panel>
                                <UploadCollection id="UploadCollection" maximumFilenameLength="55" multiple="true" showSeparators="None" items="{/AttachmentsSet}"
                                    change="onChange" fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" uploadComplete="onUploadComplete">
                                    <UploadCollectionItem fileName="{Filename}" mimeType="{MimeType}" url="{url}"/>
                                </UploadCollection>
                            </Panel>
                        </IconTabFilter>-->
                    </items>
                </IconTabBar>
                <footer>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button id="idSubmit" text="{i18n>save}" press="OnSave" type="Emphasized" icon="sap-icon://add"/>
                        <Button id="idApprove" text="{i18n>approve}" press="OnApprove" type="Accept" icon="sap-icon://accept"/>
                        <Button id="idCancel" text="{i18n>close}" press="onNavBack" type="Reject" icon="sap-icon://sys-cancel"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </footer>
            </Page>
        </detailPages>
    </SplitApp>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Is the table bound with the fetched data with two way binding? Also, please try to add the code and snapshots where you are facing the issues.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the ODataModel. Used the version 2 of ODataModel which solved the issue.

[ODataModel v2 API Documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)

Answer (score 0):

From the [SDK documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table)

> In order to keep the document DOM as lean as possible, the Table control reuses its DOM elements of the rows. When the user scrolls, only the row contexts are changed but the **rendered controls remain the same**. This allows the Table control to handle huge amounts of data. Nevertheless, restrictions apply regarding the number of displayed columns. Keep the number as low as possible to improve performance. Due to the nature of tables, the used control for column templates also has a big influence on the performance.

Emphasis mine. I think the behavior you're describing is as designed.

How much data are you displaying this way? If you don't need to display thousands of lines, you might be better of going with `sap.m.Table` which does not do this.

Comment: See my answer above. ODataModel v2 solved the problem. Thank you for your reply.